# Error in get("hulls2iso.rgeos", 1) : object 'hulls2iso.rgeos' not found

Tags: object, get, environment-variables

I created an `lhs` object using the function as follows:

```
am321.lhs <- lxy.lhs(am321.lxy.every4th, k=24, s=0.07, kmin=12, save.hulls=TRUE)
```

However, when I try to create isopleths by the following call I get an error. I have pasted the console output below:

```
am321.lhs <- lhs.iso.add(am321.lhs)
```

Using nearest-neighbor selection mode: Fixed-k
Constructing hulls and hull metrics...

```
am321.pts26934.k24.s0.07.kmin12
  Found a suitable set of nearest neighbors 
  Identifying the boundary points for each parent point 
  |++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++| 100%
  Converting boundary points into polygons
  |++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++| 100%
  Calculating area and perimeter...Done.
  Calculating the time span of each hull...Done.
  Identifying enclosed points...Done.
  Computing density isopleths 
Error in get("hulls2iso.rgeos", 1) : object 'hulls2iso.rgeos' not found
```

I would be grateful for any help on this.

Thank you
Karpa

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error recently and got the following advice from Andy Lyons:

You've encountered a bug in the package. Please update the package to version 1.40 (or later), and it should work.

### Check package version

```
packageVersion("tlocoh")
```

### Update package (if the package is already loaded, you may need to detach it or restart R to update)

```
update.packages(oldPkgs="tlocoh", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. All is well with the newer version. Andy wrote to me the same thing. I was just waiting to generate isolpleths for all my data to check if the error message reappears before posting the suggested fix.